# Working on MS Office 2013 Documents from Web Applications?

Tags: javascript, ms-office

Can anyone please tell me if we can work on Office from a Web Application using [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp142185.aspx). Is MS offering a new method of integrating MS to Web App for Web Developers mainly?
Is so is it directly from a Browser?

Comment: I think Office 365 is just a Cloud Solution and not meant for Browser Interaction with Office ? Cloud as in user's can get Exchange , Chat etc on a real MS Server with paid subscription and Office continues to be same desktop app , with a Web App ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create Active X objects in windows using javascript and manipulate Office documents. The page is the documentation of various API's.

You need to include Office.js in your HTML to make it work

```
<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.0/hosted/office.js"/>
```

For other application-specific implementation, you have to download or refer their own specific .js files from CDN.

For more information about using it you can view the msdn:

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp160953.aspx
```

Comment: Do u man I could do things like publish a PDF out of a web doc - parse contents - replace contents ? Any idea is it cross browser compatible ?

Comment: Yes it is cross browser compatible, Microsoft have done a lot of work for this project and as we all know they are the best in their office product.

Comment: Thanks Ankit ,  Is that different from Office 365 ? Please see the comment in my question .